# how to combine two table columns into one table with selected column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two table TableA and TableB. I would like to get a new table value where I want all values of TableA and only one column value from TableB. 
Both table has 5 columns where four column names are same, only fifth column name is different. What I want is to get five column values from TableA and insert the fifth column values from TablelB into TableA as sixth Column

I tried with UNION, UNION ALL but didn't get the expected output. I also tried to extraxt fifth column value from TableB and insert into TableA on sixth column but not sure where I did wrong. not getting value as expected

Sample data:

**TableA**

```
id  name age address entrydatetime
1    AA   20  tyk    2019-05-13:8:35:00
2    AAA  22  tyl    2019-05-13:9:40:00
```

**TableB**

```
id  name age address exitdatetime
1    AA   20  tyk    2019-05-13:15:20:00
2    AAA  22  tyl    2019-05-13:16:40:00
```

Expected output:
**NewTable**

```
id  name age address entrydatetime         exitdatetime
1    AA   20  tyk    2019-05-13:8:35:00    2019-05-13:15:20:00
2    AAA  22  tyl    2019-05-13:8:35:00    2019-05-13:16:40:00
```

Comment: A good ol' [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is what you need

Answer (score 1):

That's as simple as:

```
SELECT A.*, B.exitdatetime
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.id = B.id;
```

You need to join the tables when you need to match a table's row to 0-N rows from another table (or maybe even the same table, treated as if it was a different one).

An even better approach would be to name each field you need and not use *. I just used it to make a quick sample.

And just for the record, the database is not normalized, you have data redundancy, which means you can have data inconsistency. For example, if this returns at least one row, you have data inconsistency:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.name != B.name OR A.age != B.age OR A.address != B.address;
```

Comment: I think he is trying to normalize the database by doing this. I'm guessing that is why he is asking about creating a new table/combining two tables based off this data.

Comment: It did not generate output the way I expected. It produces four rows where I expect in rows since I do not wanna print id, name age, address doubles.

Comment: My first query should not return that, as it's joining by id, and the ids are unique, as per your post. As you can see, the query does `A.id = B.id`, so you should get two rows only, exactly as  your expected output. Maybe the `id` in your real data is not unique?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your reply again. here id's are not unique. Those values are not exactly as ids. They are in different column name. First four column name and values are same, only fifth column name and value is different.

Comment: Well, that's something new. Having a column called `id` which is not unique is an ugly thing to have... So you have to join by whatever condition you need to match the records, instead of just `id`.

Comment: Basically these two tables are output from other queries. This is why first four columns values and names are same. still trying to make it work

Comment: Then I guess you need to update your question with more details... Otherwise, you are on your own.

Comment: Still there, @Xone?